# How to get DevExpress GridControl cell single click event in wpf?

Tags: wpf, devexpress, gridcontrol

I am creating a demo project in wpf application I am also using DevExpress GridControl in this application my problem is that I want get the cell value in on click particular cell.

Comment: You should post this in DevExpress forums, They can answer this quickly http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should look at the `HitInfo` class.

Try this [link](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument770).

```
GridHitInfo hitInfo = gridView1.CalcHitInfo(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
if(hitInfo.InRowCell){
    object value = View.GetRowCellValue(hitInfo.RowHandle, hitInfo.Column);
    //...
}
```

Comment: Hi CalcHitInfo only works with the GridView and not the GridControll

Comment: You can access the view of your `GridControl` through `gridControl1.MainView` (for instance)

Comment: thanks found another way to achieve the same functionality :)

Comment: i checked for the MainView  property in the control http://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraGridGridControlMembersTopicAll